# replace path value of a variable in file with bash

Tags: bash, replace, sed, path, cat

I have a namelist containing inputs for simulations. I have to change the path of some variables using bash. The text file has the following value that I would like to change:

opt_path = '/home/gle/test_workflow',

I would like to replace the value of opt_path with cat and sed, and I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
new_path=/my/new/path

cat namelist.wps | sed "s/^opt_path.*/opt_path = '${new_path}'/g"
```

it returns the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 29: unknown option to `s'
```

Someone has an idea?

**EDIT:**
After some trials, the following code worked.

```
#!/bin/bash

new_path=/my/new/path
cat namelist.wps | sed "s|^.* opt_path =.*$| opt_path = '${new_path}', |g" > namelist.wps.new
```

Though it is working only with one whitespace between = character. How can I specify *any* number of whitespace between opt_path, =, and the value?

Thanks,
Greg

Comment: You're missing a filename argument to the initial `sed` command.  When you say it "doesn't work", does it give an error message, or not perform the substitution?

Comment: Sorry I forgot the cat namelist.wps. It gives the error above.

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape slashes in regexes. Otherwise `sed` thinks you're ending the `s` command.

The `new_path` variable needs to look like this: `\/my\/new\/path`

Alternatively, you can use different separators:

`sed "s|^opt_path.*|opt_path = '${new_path}'|g"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this (example for bash):

```
#!/bin/bash

new_path=/my/new/path

echo "opt_path = '/home/gle/test_workflow'" | sed -E "s|(^opt_path[ ]*=[ ]*')([^']*)|\1$new_path|g"
```

I used `echo` instead of `cat` for copy and paste ready to run code.

Comment: It is working with echo, but the variable is not changed in the file when I do: `cat namelist.wps | sed -E "s|(^opt_path[ ]*=[ ]*')([^']*)|\1$new_path|g" > namelist.new.wps`

Comment: Could you please try if this one works: `echo "opt_path = '/home/gle/test_workflow'" | sed -E "s|(opt_path[ ]*=[ ]*')([^']*)|\1$new_path|g"` In your proposed solution you changed the regex so that opt_path is not always at the beginning of a line.

Comment: It is working with echo but now when I do it with cat on the file: `cat namelist.wps | sed -E "s|(opt_path[ ]*=[ ]*')([^']*)|\1$new_path|g"`

Answer (score 0):

try this one

sed -i "s#^opt_path.*#opt_path='$new_path'#g" namelist.wps

use using delimiter as / so it would throw error message while more than one / occures in new_path variable.
you can use any character as delimiter.